# R Combining Rows with Factors and Numeric Values

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine rows in a data frame with factors and numeric values.
Here's an example similar to what I'm trying to do.

```
Letter Freq
a      .1
b      .2
c      .3
d      .4
```

I'd like to combine rows 1, 2, and 3 for example and get...

```
Letter Freq
group  .6
d      .4
```

Usually I can find something similar on this site, but I'm not sure if I'm not searching on the right terminology, or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to change the first three `levels` in 'Letter' to 'group' and then use `aggregate` to get the `sum` of 'Freq' by 'Letter'

```
levels(df1$Letter)[1:3]  <- "group"
aggregate(Freq~Letter, df1, sum)
#   Letter Freq
#1   group  0.6
#2       d  0.4
```

Comment: Thanks, so let's say I had to sort my data, so a, b, and c are not actually 1:3. How do I grab particular rows such as 26, 17, 24, and 10 (in a larger set of data)?

Comment: @ChristopherFlach   You can try `levels(df1$Letter)[levels(df1$Letter) %in% c('a', 'b', 'c')] <- "group"`